# Get Current Page URL From Bookmark on toolbar using PHP

Tags: php, url, bookmarks

I am looking to get the url of current page in url bar

> [BookMark Button In Tool Bar] - User Presses it while on a youtube link 
>   and sends it to sitename.com/test.php

The url in the bookmark then prints something like

```
sitename.com/test.php?url=http://www.youtbe.com/whateverwatever
```

I tried using referrer bur since it's coming from a bookmark link it won't work 
I also tried the referrer in Javascript but it still won't work

Comment: right, because there is no referrer

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want `window.location.href`. That'll get the current location then you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, as there isn't a referrer if you click a bookmark.

If you're trying to make a "share this" bookmark sort of thing, you can use some JavaScript to make a "bookmarklet". Delicious has [a bookmarklet](http://www.delicious.com/help/bookmarklets) that does this sort of thing.